# Haskell: all names in Haskell are immutable? No difference between array and list?

Tags: arrays, list, haskell, immutability, mutable

I have two questions:

1. In FP langauges like scala or F#, there are keywords to identify whether a variable is mutable or not. When we say Haskell is a pure FP language, everything is "immutable"?
2. Scala based on jvm, F# based on .net, both differentiate between "Array" and "List". Does Haskell tells this different, or every container in Haskell is a "list" or "tuple"?

Comment: Haskell formalizes mutation as IO (because that's what it is). For example, [`IORef`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-IORef.html) provides mutable references, and [`Array.IO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.1.0/docs/Data-Array-IO.html) provides mutable arrays.

Comment: There are also state threads (`ST`) that offer locally mutable arrays.

Answer (score 3):

In Haskell, all *variables* are immutable. However, there are various special data structures that support mutation. For a start, you can read and write files in Haskell, and you could consider a file as a giant mutable variable. But of course, Haskell also supports in-memory mutable structures (`IORef`, `STRef`, `MVar`, `TVar`, etc.) So (for example) the variable `x` always points to the same `IORef` object, but the contents of that object can be changed.

Mutating stuff is considered a side-effect, which in Haskell is controlled via monads. If a function's type signature doesn't mention `IO`, then you can't perform any I/O operations. That includes mutating in-memory data that other threads can see. (But, interestingly, *doesn't* include mutating data only visible to this function. So you can do mutation inside a pure function, so long as there are no externally visible effects of this.)

Haskell "defaults to" immutable single-linked lists, but also supports both immutable and mutable arrays. Modifying an immutable array requires copying the entire array, turning update in to an O(n) operation, and thus destroying a key advantage of arrays. Immutable arrays still make an excellent look-up table for constant data, but most array-based algorithms want *mutable* arrays, which is why those are also provided.

Answer (score 1):

"Purity" is not a rigorously defined concept. In Haskell, it generally means that functions do not have side effects. But "side effect" is not really rigorously defined either. Haskell's type system allows us to distinguish between pure functions `a -> b` and impure actions `IO a`. Not everything is immutable, because you can use an IO action to change the contents of an `IORef`, for example.

Haskell also has arrays, several different versions of them, but they are found in modules which you have to import.

Comment: I would say everything in *Haskell* is immutable. `IO a` is just a type Haskell programs can produce that is interpreted (outside Haskell proper) as an imperative program.

Comment: @dfeuer: Could you elaborate on that argument?  What is the point of defining "Haskell" in such a way that you can't execute or evaluate anything?

Comment: I mean, one could equally define "C" in the same way. You could say everything in "pure C" is immutable, it's the CPU that changes memory according to the instructions contained in a C program.

Comment: Sure. The C preprocessor produces C code which is interpreted externally. But you can do a heck of a lot more reasoning in pure Haskell than in pure C.

Comment: @dfeuer: But you can't *evaluate expressions* in "pure" Haskell, by that definition.  You can only reason about types.  At that point you're not using Haskell as a programming language, but as a proof system.  In which case, it's a rather poor proof system compared to the alternatives.  I think you're going to have a very hard time finding anyone who shares this particular definition of Haskell.

Comment: Part of the point is that there *is* a sense in which you can do pure computations with IO in Haskell, separate from executing them. They're first class values, and when you're just building them and passing them around all the usual laws about pure Haskell code applies (see especially when you apply monad-generic functions to IO actions). It's only the execution of `main` that is different, and it's not hard to see that as "external" since no language facilities in Haskell can actually talk about it (other than defining `main`).

Comment: @DietrichEpp, Conal Elliott and others seem to think it's pretty important to distinguish between the pure language and whatever notion of interaction gets tacked onto it. FRP aims to model interaction in very different ways than `IO`. Yes, these days that's ultimately kicked off by a little stubby `main :: IO a`, but the activists view that as nothing more than an implementation artifact.

Comment: I understand that it's important to be able to distinguish between the different parts of it.  But the "pure" part is only useful because the impure part exists.  Saying that the impure part is "not Haskell" is just ridiculous.

Comment: The "pure part"+"impure part" way of framing things is, I suspect, responsible for a lot of the confusion beginners face when learning about `IO`. They expect to evaluate an action, see something happen, and get a result, ML-style.

Comment: @dfeuer: If you think you have a better way of framing things, please post a link or add your own answer, or put something in the comments here.  But you seem to be framing things exactly the same way.  You seem to be saying that there is a "pure part"+"impure part", but you call them "Haskell"+"Not Haskell" or something like that.  That sounds like you are taking my explanation and applying an α-conversion to it.